# How to handle a Java package split between two directories with Maven

Tags: java, maven, osgi, tycho

I have found a package I want to use, it's using Maven, but it's sources are split between two directories, one of them contains auto-generated stuff, the other, .xtend source files.

The problem is, these directories "can't see each other" when compiling; this used to work given build reports from two years ago on the same project.

Conjecture: This broke because of a change between Maven 3.5 and 3.6, I guess it used to add all source directories to the classpath first, then compiled the files, but it doesn't anymore, now I see only the current one, although both are reported as source directories.

I don't want to restructure the project to fix these errors.

So given two directories, A and B, what's the proper way to add B to the classpath from A, and A from B, so that this works as it is?

I've reduced it to:

```
project/
  |- src/
  |- src-gen/
  |- xtend-gen/
  |- .classpath
  |- build.properties
  `- pom.xml
```

## `build.properties`:

```
source.. = src/,\
           src-gen/,\
           xtend-gen/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .
additional.bundles = org.apache.commons.logging
```

## `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.example.lang.dsl</artifactId>
        <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
        <build>
                <resources>
                        <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/xtext</directory>
                        </resource>
                </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/xtext</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.mwe2</include>
                                        <include>**/*.xtext</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.fornax.toolsupport</groupId>
                <artifactId>fornax-oaw-m2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xtext</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-workflow</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <workflowEngine>mwe2</workflowEngine>
                            <workflowDescriptor>com.example.lang.dsl.GenerateComp</workflowDescriptor>
                            <timestampFileName>gen.timestamp</timestampFileName>
                            <jvmSettings>
                                <fork>true</fork>
                                <jvmArgs>
                                    <jvmArg>-Xms128m</jvmArg>
                                    <jvmArg>-Xmx512m</jvmArg>
                                    <jvmArg>-XX:MaxPermSize=128m</jvmArg>
                                </jvmArgs>
                            </jvmSettings>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
                <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <version>0.1</version>
</project>
```

Comment: either they are in one package, or they are in one directory, which is it?

Comment: First please show an example of your pom file and best would be a working example project which shows the behaviour...apart from that a directory is not added to the classpath only a jar (dependency) and your last sentence sounds like a circular reference which will not work...please describe more in detail....

Comment: Autogenerated files need to be put into a specific folder in target/ for this to work to my understanding.  Would using an older version of Maven be an option?

Comment: Yes if you have generated code which is usually put into `target/generated-source/XXX` where usually XXX is replaced with the identifying information about the plugin which generated that...The question is: Does the used plugin handle that correctly which I think is the real issue...That a Maven upgrade breaks that I have my doubts about that...Are you using the same version of the plugin as before?

Comment: Have the plugin versions somewhere defined?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen not an option for this project.

Comment: @khmarbaise sadly no, and all I got is a build log, I wish to import this into a newer environment, so I can glue it to other stuff.

Comment: @khmarbaise I have no experience with Maven, so I'm a litte bit lost, and mostly relying on guesswork.